# when I use the event.keycode to execute my function it dont execute but if put an alert it works

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function multiplicacion() {
    var x = document.getElementById("v1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("v2").value;
    var z = (x * y)

    document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = z
}

function division() {
    var x = document.getElementById("v1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("v2").value;
    var z = (x / y)

    document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = z
}

function suma() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value);
    var z
    z = x + y
    document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = z

}

function resta() {

    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("v2").value);
    var z
    z = x - y
    document.getElementById("salida").innerHTML = z

}

function PulsarTecla(event){

    tecla = event.keyCode;
 
    if(tecla == 189){
       resta
    }
}
 
window.onkeydown=PulsarTecla;
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>
<div align = "center">
            <font size = "5" id = "salida"> 0 </font>
            <input  type="text" name="v1" id="v1">
            <input  type="text" name="v2" id="v2"><br><br>
            <button  id="multiplicacion" onclick="multiplicacion()" class="button1">X</button>
            <button  id="division" onclick="division()" class="button3">/</button><br><br>
            <button  id="suma" onclick="suma()" class="suma">+</button>
            <button  id="resta" onclick="resta()" class="resta">-</button>
        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

the problem is that I try to execute the "resta" function with the slash but it dont works, it only works with the buttons, I´ve only try this with the "resta" function
First I try to execute an alert with the slash and it works but no with the function

Comment: FYI, `event.keycode` is deprecated. You'd want `event.key` instead. Also `resta` is not being executed, you'd need `resta()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are missing brackets in the function `PulsarTecla`. There is an identifier of another function `resta` but no brackets so this function isn't actually called.

This code should work:

```
function PulsarTecla(event){

    tecla = event.keyCode;

    if(tecla == 189){
       resta()
    }
}
```